# Apply margin left if class is present

Tags: html, css, sass

So I created a solution that I needed, but it turned into another problem that I'm having trouble solving.

So here is what I'm attempting to achieve:

- I'd like to define `margin-left: 60px` to `.dropdown-content:after` if the dropdown has a combination of classes `<div class="dropdown is-right">`.
- Otherwise, I'd like to define `margin-top: -11px` on `.dropdown-content:after` if the dropdown doesn't have `is-right`, such as `<div class="dropdown">`.

All help would be appreciated, I attempted it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the `HTML`:

```
<div class="dropdown is-right">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <?php if ($user): ?>
    <a class="navbar-item level is-mobile" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu2">
        <p>Test</p>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu2" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                My Profile
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                Settings
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `SASS`:

```
.dropdown
  &.is-right

  .dropdown-content

    &:after
      content: ''
      position: absolute
      top: 0
      left: 35%
      margin-left: 60px
      margin-top: -11px
      width: 0
      z-index: 1
      height: 0
      border-bottom: solid 15px #FFF
      border-left: solid 15px transparent
      border-right: solid 15px transparent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way you'd do it in plain CSS: Concatenate the classes that are on the same element.

```
.dropdown
  .dropdown-content
    &:after
      // This compiles to: .dropdown .dropdown-content:after
      content: ''
      position: absolute
      top: 0
      left: 35%
      margin-top: -11px
      width: 0
      z-index: 1
      height: 0
      border-bottom: solid 15px #FFF
      border-left: solid 15px transparent
      border-right: solid 15px transparent

  &.is-right
    .dropdown-content
      &:after
        // This compiles to: .dropdown.is-right .dropdown-content:after
        margin-top: 0
        margin-left: 60px
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks @Ouroborus, something new learned - If you could upvote my question, would highly appreciate it.